# Apply CSS styles to a visited link on hover

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, css-specificity

What I want to do is have the background of my links in the body content of a WordPress page on my website change styles on hover, but only if it is a *visited link*.

This is what I've tried already:

```
/* Page content hover styles */
.page .entry-content a:hover:visited {
   background: #C5C5E8 !important;
}
```

But, even with the `!important` it is still not taking effect. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the page in question:

https://erichepperle.com/about/

How can I apply styles upon hovering a visited link?

---

### UPDATE:

Here is my About page today 2018-08-20. I'm following up and testing proposed solutions and these images will help clarify my responses.

Fig 1.
[image: EricHepperle.com About page - Hover on visited link doesn't work]

Here is the code I added to test @Johannes's answer:

`.page .entry-content a:visited:hover {
    background: purple;
    font-style: oblique;
}`

Comment: @halfer Thanks for trim editing my post. About 2 years ago I got a really good response from contributors based on how I organized (with scannable subheading, etc.) my questions. That led me to believe my practice was better than what others were doing, just leaving quick messages without commentary and also not bothering to thank folks in advance. It seems, based on your edits that either you have your own style you are imposing, or #bestPractices changed. If the case is the latter, can you point me to a link of new SO community best practices so I can know how to format my posts? Thanks

Comment: I'm not too bothered by the headings; I think they are unnecessary for a short post, so I removed them while addressing other items. I would not edit out headings if that was the only issue, and do not object to them in general. There were two issues here: too chatty (you've not found anything in your research, you appreciate help, an ordered list containing only one item); a link to your website, where presumably the issue would have been demonstrated (presumably until it is fixed).

Comment: Related reading: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Looking at this question again, I now wonder if it is on-topic, since the only _demonstration_ of the problem is the external link (assuming it has not been fixed there). If you can edit this question to demonstrate the problem in a more self-contained way, that would be ideal - you may know we wish to keep questions for posterity here, and thus links to websites are not ideal ways of showing what the problem was at the time.

Comment: (If you can indicate whether this was fixed on your site, that might help us to work out whether an answer below can be accepted, or whether a self-answer could be written, or whether you wish to abandon the question. Sometimes these things feed into whether the question should be put on hold too. Hope this helps!)

Comment: @halfer Yes, I agree with your assessment. This was one of the rare times that I just quickly posted something without outlining it. It has been awhile since I posted so let me examine the website and then I will post back today.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, this is an improvement. However, the best way to show the issue is to create a Stack snippet (using the built-in editor), a JS Fiddle or some other external HTML/CSS/JS runner. This is both reproducible and self-contained. I don't plan to cast a close vote, but perhaps something to bear in mind for future questions.

Comment: I am aware of the minimally verifiable code snippets and have created them before when necessary. But, I'm not sure how to make one for this example because I believe the issue is with my code, I just haven't been able to pinpoint it for some reason. I know this will be valuable for others with similar questions -- as realizing that the visited and the hover need to be switched may solve their problem, it doesn't seem to be solving mine. I'm typing the css into the wordpress configurator > Additional CSS realtime editor, which should apply with highest priority (except for inline).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178371/discussion-between-eric-hepperle-codeslayer2010-and-halfer).

Answer (score 3):

Use `a:visited:hover` (note the order)

```css
a:link {
color: red;
}
a:visited {
color: green;
}
a:hover {
color: yellow;
}
a:visited:hover {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Testtest</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Johannes. I've already tried using `.page .entry-content a:visited:hover` and it doesn't work. Are you able to make it work successfully on the page link I provided in my question? https://erichepperle.com/about/

Comment: yes, I tried it and it works (I used `!important` since I only wrote `a:visited:hover`)

Comment: Hmm ok. Do I have to include every permutation like you did? Do you think that might be my stumbling block at the moment?

Comment: I don't think so, but you have to make sure that this one rule (`:visited:hover`)  follows *after* the other ones.

Comment: I'll try it out and report back, might not be today though. Thanks.

Comment: I realized I hadn't resolve this yet so I wanted to follow up. There are two major differences between your answer and my original code: 1) You are not using !important and 2) your answer uses `a:visited:hover`, whereas mine used `a:hover:visited`. Your answer looked promising, but I couldn't get it to work. See fig. 1 and the code I used, in the body above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mnemonic to remember the order of: **Link, Visited, Hover, Active**. The letters are **L, V, H, A**, so you can use [**L**o**V**e, **HA**te](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/).

```
a:link {color: blue;}        ->  unvisited link
a:visited {color: purple;}   ->  visited link
a:hover {color: red;}        ->  mouse over link
a:active {color: yellow;}    ->  selected link
```

Since you want to apply style for a visited link on hover

You can use **a:visited:hover**.

You can also check out:

[CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

[CSS Link Pseudo-classes](https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/link-pseudo-classes/)

Comment: Thanks Akash. I had forgotten that acronym from my Advanced CSS & Preprocessors course in college.